# Difference between "Raubvogel" und "Raubtier"

Tags: meaning

Title says it all, is there a major difference between "Raubvogel" and "Raubtier"? Aren't all "animals" that are counted as Raubvögel also Raubtiere?

Comment: Selbst dann bliebe ja der Unterschied, dass das eine eine echte Obermenge des anderen ist, also mächtiger. Ein Gepard ist gewiss kein Raubvogel, aber ein Raubtier, selbst wenn man um die Taxonomie der Biologie weiß.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In biological taxonomy, *Raubtiere* only refers to carnivorous mammals and does not include *Raubvögel*.

There's a very general layman's understanding of the term *Raubtiere* that just means "animals that eat meat", and if you're using that, it could include mammalian carnivores, carnivorous fish (*Raubfische*), crocodiles, birds of prey (*Raubvögel*) etc. A more correct but rarely used term for this group is *Prädatoren*.

Answer (score 4):

Raub*vogel* is only describing a *Vogel*, i. e. *bird of prey*.
Raub*tier*, on the other hand, is a broader expression describing an animal (mainly a mammal) that does feed on other animals.

Hence, a *Raubvogel* is also a *Raubtier*, but not the other way 'round.

Answer (score 0):

No. In the older sorting scheme, *Raubtiere* are a class of mammals.

Both *Raubvögel* and *Raubtiere* are nowadays put under the umbrella term *Beutegreifer*.

Comment: You might want to extend your statement on "Beutegreifer" with a remark that this is very rare.

Answer (score 0):

I think at the root of the question might be a misunderstanding of how **word formation** works. I will therefore try to answer more generally.

The products of word formation processes such as *raub-* + *Tier* → *Raubtier* always have the potential to become independent units, i.e. new **lexemes**. This is what happened in the field of biology:  *Raubtier* designates an order of mammals. Therefore, as a technical term, *Raubtier* cannot refer to a bird despite the fact that birds are animals. This **lexicalisation** or **idiomatisation** of the compound entails that knowing the meaning of *rauben* and *Tier* is not sufficient for knowing the meaning of *Raubtier*.

However, even once a new lexeme has been established, the potential for **spontaneous** or **ad hoc formations** remains, i.e. one could form a new compound (or a new meaning of the compound) *Raubtier* in a specific situation. For instance, if a dog were to habitually steal my slippers, I could refer to it as *Raubtier* and the term would be understood as referring to the dog's behaviour (and not an order of mammals or a carnivorous diet).

Let's look at another example: Agent nouns on *-er* can denote persons or machines. Consequently, *Mischer* is someone or something that mixes. However, *Giftmischer* denotes a person and *Betonmischer* a machine, i.e. the meaning of the compound is more limited than the nominal base suggests. This is a mild case of lexicalisation. But there is always the potential for ad hoc formations. For instance, if my partner was using a blender to create smoothies that I find unappealing, I could refer to the blender as *Giftmischer* and expect to be understood.

Comment: "Raubtier designates an order of mammals. Therefore, as a technical term, Raubtier cannot refer to a bird despite the fact that birds are animals." - while correct in biological terminology, I think it should also be pointed out that is not how the term is commonly understood in everyday language, where "Raubtier" is pretty much synonymous with "Fleischfresser". For instance, I'm pretty sure the vast majority of native speakers would consider a statement like "Ein Krokodil ist ein Raubtier." correct.

Comment: I think this is a case of **remotivation**: *raub-* + X is reanalysed as *carnivorous X*.

Comment: Possibly - what does "Raub" in the biological term "Raubtiere" refer to?

Comment: In the case of *Raubtiere* = *carnivora* it does not have to refer to anything; once the compound has been lexicalised, the meaning of the parts can narrow, float or disappear (at least, *raub-* isn't "rob" and *Tiere* isn't animals).

Comment: Sure, the meaning of the individual parts may change or get lost altogether once the compound has formed. Yet, presumably, the compound was originally not created entirely randomly - say, given what whoever coined the term wanted to describe, "Raubtiere" was probably seen as a better choice than "Wolkenpudding" or "Bücherschneise". I am asking what "Raub" was presumably referring to during that decision process.

Comment: That seems like a new question!

Comment: [Created.](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72658/warum-hei%c3%9fen-raubtiere-raubtiere)

Comment: *Tier* may be historically more narrow than today. Its English cognate *dear* is very narrow. *Raub* could conceivably be related to a root for "blood", related to *roh*, En. *raw*, also in Gothic  *hraiwadubō* "turtle-dove" (?), etc. Slavic *ruba* "fish" is of uncertain origin, indicating some breaking change, which Germanic may have shared. *Raub* is otherwise related to Sanskrit *lopa*, Latin *rupa, rupta*, etc., and since *lupus* "wolf" is uncertain, well, you get the idea—cross talk.

Comment: @DavidVogt: It looks like the conclusion from the [other question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72658) is that *raub-* + X as *carnivorous X* is not a remotivation, but rather matches the original meaning of that part of the composite word spot-on. If anything, it's the -tier part that has been remotivated to match the contemporary understanding of "Tier", rather than a, possibly narrower, earlier one.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Do native speakers know the original meaning (i.e. *Raub* = *Beute des Raubtiers* )? I didn't. And the examples under DWB [Raub 2b)](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=R01167) and [rauben 4)](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=R01188) seem strange to me (whereas the converse term *Beutetier* poses no problem). In hindsight, what I actually think about when I hear *Raubtier, Raubvogel, Raubmöwe* is violence; so *Raubtier* in its non-technical sense could be completely transparent if it is understood as "violent animal".

Comment: But the point of the answer was that such analysis of compounds isn't necessary. They can be treated as a whole, as I would the technical term *Raubtiere* = "the order Carnivora".