# Warum heißen Raubtiere "Raubtiere"?

Tags: etymology

Bei den Antworten einer [kürzlich hier erschienenen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72639/difference-between-raubvogel-und-raubtier/72646) wurde mir in einem [Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72639/difference-between-raubvogel-und-raubtier/72646?noredirect=1#comment173816_72646) zur wörtlichen Bedeutung von "Raubtier" Folgendes mitgeteilt:

> I think this is a case of **remotivation**: *raub-* + X is reanalysed as *carnivorous X*.

Das legt offenbar nahe, dass der Wortbestandteil "Raub-" in "Raubtier" ursprünglich keine semantische Verbindung zum Aspekt des Fleischfressens oder des Jagens nach Beute hatte.

Gleichwohl gehe ich davon aus, dass der Wortbestandteil "Raub-" nicht rein zufällig gewählt wurde, sondern man sich schon irgendetwas dabei gedacht hat, die betreffenden Tiere so zu bezeichnen.

**Welche Information sollte der Wortbestandteil "Raub-" in "Raubtier" ursprünglich vermitteln?**

Comment: [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Raubtier) liefert da eine sehr umfangreiche etymologische Auflistung, gibt es daran Zweifel?

Comment: Find ich ein bißchen übertrieben, Pfeifers Vermerk *Entsprechend Raubtier n. (Anfang 18. Jh.)* als "sehr umfangreich" zu bezeichnen (und dann gleich die Frage abzuwerten).

Comment: @infinitezero: Na ja, wie schon im [anderen Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72658#comment173826_72658) angedeutet, dreht sich der Großteil der etymologischen Auflistung um das grundlegende Wort "rauben", ohne konkret auf die Interpretation von "rauben" im Kompositum "Raubtier" einzugehen. Ich persönlich *vermute* durchaus, dass dieses "Raub-" mit dem Entreißen von Fleisch, der "Beschlagnahme" des Beutetiers zu tun hat, habe aber keine geeigneten Quellen gefunden, um dies stichhaltig zu widerlegen - und auch der genannte DWDS-Artikel ist dazu wie gesagt viel zu ...

Comment: ... implizit. Der Autor des in meiner Frage zitierten Kommentars zweifelt andererseits offenbar durchaus daran, dass dieses "Raub-" in "Raubtier" *ursprünglich* irgendeine inhaltliche Verbindung zum Fleischfressen hatte. Deshalb würde ich der Sache gerne auf den Grund gehen und Belege für die von mir vermutete, oder möglicherweise auch eine davon abweichende Bedeutung zu finden, statt rein nach Gefühl herumzuraten.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper "Der Autor des in meiner Frage zitierten Kommentars zweifelt andererseits offenbar durchaus daran, dass dieses "Raub-" in "Raubtier" *ursprünglich* irgendeine inhaltliche Verbindung zum Fleischfressen hatte." – Ich glaube nicht, daß das aus dem folgt, was ich geschrieben habe? An **irgendeiner** Beziehung zweifle ich nicht, schon gar nicht, wenn auch noch die Geschichte ("ursprünglich") mit einbezogen wird.

Comment: Es scheint ziemlich [offensichtlich](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Raubtier)...

Comment: @DavidVogt: Deinen Kommentar fasste ich so auf, dass du davon ausgingst, der Bezug von "Raub-" zu "fleischfressend" sei erst nachträglich ins "Raubtier" hineininterpretiert worden. Deshalb stuftest du es doch als "remotivation" (Remotivierung) ein (also eine ["semantische Umdeutung eines (...) Ausdrucks"](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Volksetymologie)), oder habe ich das falsch verstanden? Genau darum wollte ich ja wissen, was denn *dann* ursprünglich mit "Raub-" gemeint war, wurde aber dazu aufgefordert, das in einer separaten Frage aufzugreifen - was ich in Form dieser Frage hier tat :)

Comment: @DavidVogt die Frage abgewertet habe ich nicht (just for the record). Und "entsprechend Raubtier" ist natürlich kurz, wenn man die 25 Zeilen vorher ignoriert....

Comment: Der Artikel [Raub](https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Raub) sagt nichts über das Kompositum *Raubtier*. –  "Remotivierung" schließt auf keinen Fall aus, daß das Wort eine ursprüngliche (mir unbekannte) Motivierung hatte, die aber vielleicht gar nicht mehr präsent ist, wenn man auf Basis von *Raubtier* "Mitglied der Ordnung Carnivora" auch *Raubmöwe* oder sogar *Raubmilbe* bilden kann und *Raubtier* dann vielleicht wieder weiter als in der Fachsprache als "fleißfressendes Tier" verstanden werden kann.

Comment: Ich verstehe die gesamte Diskussion nicht. Ein Raubvogel, ist einer der Beute macht. Dass Raub vor ein paar Hundert Jahren nicht exakt den gleichen Bedeutungsumfang hatte wie heute sollte nicht überraschen. Was sonst David Vogt meinte, kann er erklären, dazu bedarf es keiner Frage hier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der Zusammenhang zwischen "Raubtier" und dem "Räuber" dürfte aus dem Lateinischen stammen (Die Taxonomie ist eine sehr frühe Wissenschaft, die schon zu einer Zeit bestand, als Latein noch die allgemeine Wissenschaftssprache war - Carl von Linné hat seine erste Taxonomie komplett in Latein verfasst):

Dort heißt das Raubtier (und der Räuber) "praedator", oder "raptor" - Substantivierungen von *praedare* bzw. *rapere*, die von "Beute erwerben, "plündern" (und natürlich "rauben") bis "schänden" oder auch einfach "nehmen" alles Mögliche bedeuten können, was eine Aktion enthält, wo jemandem gegen seinen Willen etwas weggenommen wird.

Als wörtliche Übersetzung für "praedator" finde ich "Beutemacher", für "raptor" "Räuber" - was für ein Raubtier schon ziemlich gut passt. Und wenn schon die alten Römer den gleichen Begriff für beides (den Raüber und das Raubtier) verwendet haben, liegt es nahe, dass auf Latein schreibende Wissenschaftler dasselbe taten.

Answer (score 2):

Der Kommentar ist von @DavidVogt. Gemeint ist, dass *Raubtier* durch Gebrauch eindeutig bestimmt ist und später wegen einer erweiterten Bedeutung des Begriffes *Tier* neu interpretiert wird.

Noch im Rolandslied wurden *tiere und vogele* getrennt (s. Grimm). Ebenso kann man *Tiere* von *Tierchen*, *Ungeziefer*, *Untier* usw. unterscheiden.

Wenn @DavidVogt *Remotivation* sagt, nehme ich an, es sei ein neues *Motiv* gemeint. Ob diese Begrifflichkeit astreines Latein ist oder selbst remotiviert ist, sei dahingestellt.

> Ich persönlich vermute durchaus, dass dieses "Raub-" mit dem Entreißen von Fleisch, der "Beschlagnahme" des Beutetiers zu tun hat, habe aber keine geeigneten Quellen gefunden, um dies stichhaltig zu widerlegen

So ähnlich dürfte es den meisten Sprechern gehen. Schließlich spricht man synonym vom *Räuber* (Raubtier), vllt. weil der Fuchs gern Schafe aus der Herde *reißt* und der Hirte sich hintergangen fühlt. Zahme Hunde, die nichtdestotrotz Fleisch fressen, sind dagegen keine Räuber.

Ausschlaggebend dürfte sein, dass das Tier sich gerne *rauft*. An der Stelle verweißt Pfeifer auf mittelirisch *robb* "(wühlendes) Tier" mit Fragezeichen versehen und vergleicht sogleich *rauben* (DWDS: raufen).

Wirklich wichtig für die Sprachwissenschaft ist jedoch der Finnische Befund, demnach das Wort *raha* für Geld von wertvollem Fell abgeleitet ist, das als Lehnwort etwa aus dem Germanischen entlehnt sein soll, wofür zuerst altnordisch *skrá* herangezogen wird: "Originally, this meant the fur of squirrel," (en.WT: [raha](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raha#Finnish)) wobei da fragwürdig ist, auf welchen Bezugspunkt "originally" gemünzt ist. In altnordisch beziehen sich die Belege wohl eher aufs Schreiben.

Die dafür angesetzte Wurzel *(s)ker- "schneiden" ist im Prinzip mit dem Anlaut *r* < *(h)r vereichbar, wobei *har* nicht auszuschließen ist, genauso für *ker- "army": Vergleich engl. *harrier* "bird of prey", *to harry* "rob, steal, plunder", zu Deutsch *Hehr* "Armee". Das sogenannte *s-mobile*, das werdenden Indogermanisten über der Krippe hängt, bleibt unterdessen ein ungeklärtes Problem. Ein noch größeres Problem sind die etlichen Vogelnamen, jene welche den jeweiligen Vogel Ruf nachahmend erklärt werden, obwohl offensichtlich ist, dass *Rabe* und *Möwe* mangels Lippen keinen Labiallaut realisieren können.

Um die Tragweite des Problems zu erläutern, muss etwas weiter ausgeholt werden. 1. Ob Indisch Rupie und Russisch Rubel verwandt seien, ist unsicher; *Rappen* wird von vornherein ausgeschlossen. Für das eine wird "rot" als Ausgangspunkt angesetzt. Weil die meisten Gegenstände Farben haben, von denen Rot naturgemäß hervorsteht, sind solche Herleitungen vielzählig anzutreffen, aber zu reduktiv um als urindogermanisch zu gelten. 2. So ähnlich wird zumindest ein Wort für Blut wegen der Farbe begründet. Ebenfalls ist *skrá* wohl mit unserem *Schorf* verwandt, aber das ist ebenfalls nicht in Stein gemeißelt. Ein derartiger Anspruch wird auch der geltwerten *Mark* zugerechnet, um gleichfalls die Grenzmark als *Abschnitt* zu erklären. Murks. 3. Da man von *rohem* Fleisch spricht, wobei das Wort im Sprachvergleich auf etwas blutiges zurückzuführen ist, sowie Tiere nachweißlich auch am Stück gehandelt wurden, kann man im Prinzip von zufälliger Verwechslung ausgehen.

Ich schließe wieder mal mit der müden Einsicht, dass dem ohne weiteres nicht beizukommen ist.

Sinngemäß handelt es sich schlicht um ein Tier, welches raubt, wobei Auslegungssache ist, welches Tier gemeint ist. Ramon-Garcia spricht beispielhaft von "Ersatzkontinuanten", was leider kaum rezipiert wird, und verkennt dabei die durch allseits beliebte Sprachspiele bestätigte Möglichkeit der sinnentstellenden Folksetymologie. Um sich dem anzuschließen, empfehle ich den Vergleich mit lat. *ruderalis*, vgl. *roh*, s. *Wild*, s. o. *Mark*, vgl. Indo-Iranisch *mrgwa- "beast" (ohne Etymologie).

Comment: Für den Teil über "raha" im Zusammenhang mit "Fell" möchte ich mal das Märchen "Allerleihrau" erwähnen, in dem auch die Bezeichnung "Rautierchen" auftaucht. Diese Namen erhält die Hauptfigur, da sie einen Mantel aus "tausenderlei" Fellen trägt.